# Turning my pc to a global server using wamp

Tags: android, server, client, wamp

[image][image]I read other threads regarding this issue,
I am trying to communicate with my pc as a server. client is an Android app.
I have managed to get a successful communication between the two only when the client and the server are connected to the same wifi SSID and share the same router.(ip 10.0.0.x)

Also tried open ports on router configuration but I couldnt get my PC reached by other clients..
wamp green indication of server up is shown
httpconf :

> Listen 0.0.0.0:9985 Listen [::0]:9985

Comment: If you are able to access it internally, then you need to configure your router to accept it and have an address that will never change to access your server.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, you will need to have either a static IP address or DDNS configured on your router. You will need to assign the port and configure proper forwarding on your router.

Comment: is it possible to config such setup with a dlink-2760u router?

Comment: You are going to have to look at advanced configurations for it. It does seem like an older router so there is a chance it does not support it

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of the screen you are talking about..or you refer to some other screen?

Comment: What kind of options do you have under DNS?

Comment: Configure dynamic DNS, then make your connection go to that dynamic DNS address.

Answer (score 0):

You can first sign up with a free dynamic DNS service such as http://www.noip.com/

Next go to your router's admin settings under DNS. They usually have an option for you to add the website (in this case noip) as well as your username and password (for the DNS service provider, not the router's pw). The rest is done automatically by your router's firmware.

Once this is set up, you should be able to connect from an external web access point to your computer.
Finally the last step (unless you have already done it) is to set up **port forwarding** on your router.

Comment: I will try DNS, but I cant see a port forwarding option in the router menu..only what you can see in the attachment..

Comment: Look under advanced setup > NAT

Answer (score 0):

set static ip to your pc and try to use any network utility  tool in android  and try to ping with your system static ip
make sure you turn off firewall and antivirus tools

Comment: ok i set it to a fixed address :10.0.0.3 ,whats next?which tool ?

Comment: listen, i already had connection before the static ip, because client is in the same ssid of the server, what i want is to be accessed from wan

Answer (score 0):

I've done this myself quite a few times. I'm not sure 9985 will work, or at least you'd have to connect to that IP (0.0.0.0:9985) in the browser to my understanding. You'll also need to configure your router and port forward 9985, if not 80/8080. I'm not sure if all routers do this, when I researched this on the web it said it wasn't possible for some, but mine does. You'll also want to make your local static IP on your computer or else it might change when you restart your router if needed.

On Windows, This can be done by going to "Networking and Sharing Center" in your control panel, then Adapter Settings, then go into Properties of your connection. Your connection can change based on what kind of networking you're using (for example Local Area Connection is what mine is called because I'm using LAN, but if you use Wireless it would be Wireless Network Connection). Right click your IPv4 adapter then go into Properties. Manually set your IP to your current IP, you'll also need your DNS server address (or alternatively you can use google's (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4). Click Ok, then Close. Wait a few minutes for it to register then go to a webpage. If you can't connect refer to: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?hl=en

You might have to look up a way to do it for Mac if you use Mac, but you get the general idea.

Also make sure that when you're connecting using your Android that you're using your static IP (http://whatsmyip.org/)

Comment: i set a static ip , but can you tel according to the screenshot if the port forwarding is supported in my router and if so which menu should i choose..?

Comment: I can't tell if your router is allowed to do it or not, but I would suggest looking it up or even calling them to see if it's possible. You have a DLink so I'm pretty sure it's possible, you just have to port forward 80 and 8080.

Make sure you're connecting to your own website through Android USING the port (http:// yourIP:9985/)